# Moving emails and setting the flag to unseen - imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I want to move the emails and set Unseen flag to the copy but I don`t know hot to get the uid of the copy without doing another iteration in the mailbox as results[0] return 'OK' and results[1] returns None. Any suggestion?

```
result = imap.uid('COPY', msg_uid, bandeja)
if result[0] == 'OK':
   mov, data = imap.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
   imap.expunge()
```

Comment: If your server doesn’t support UIDPLUS, the only way is to switch to the destination folder and search for it.  However, why not try set the flags before copying it, if you’re just going to delete it anyway?  Also check if your server supports UID MOVE.

Comment: I put the flag before copying it and it worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: I will convert to an answer since that was helpful enough for you.

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools may helpful

Comment: No, it is not because it is higher level and I want a lower level coding to get taylor-made code but Thank You for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server does not support the `UIDPLUS` extension (most do!), you would have to `select` the new folder and then search for the message you just copied.

However, in this case (since you seem to just be doing a message move) is to change the flags *before* you copy it, and the copied message should inherit the flags.